# Analyzing Ryuichi Sakamoto "Merry Christmas, Mr. Laurence"

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, analysis

[image]

[image]

The original song is not in C Maj key
but the sheet I Have is in C Maj so let just see as the key is in C maj

(The [B] part starts 1:50)

How does the Gm (Vm) come about?

Is it a modal interchange chord Vm (sub dominant) from the Mixolydian scale?

And if I'm right about Gm being a modal interchange chord from Mixolydian, how does this connect to Dm?

Comment: Btw, this is clearly inspired by Debussy's "Claire de Lune", so analysis of that may help you to figure out what Sakamoto is doing, and why.

Comment: @YourUncleBob which part of "Claire de Lune" should I look ?

Comment: It seems to be built around the underlying theme of Clair de Lune. E.g. in this recording: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fvo_iOuSck it's most recognisable between 0:26 and 0:44, but the theme crops up in various guises throughout the piece.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition about the Gm is absolutely correct: it's just a result of mode mixture, also called modal interchange.

Before this Gm9, we have FM7–G7–Am7, which is really a IV7–V7–vi7 progression in C major. The Gm9 is then just a chord borrowed from C Mixolydian; instead of a V9 chord, we now have a v9 chord. I think borrowing from Mixolydian is better than borrowing from the parallel minor of C minor. If we were borrowing from C minor, we'd likely have an A♭ as well, which we don't.

At this point, the Gm9 moving to Dm is simply a v–ii progression in C. (You could also think of these as being brief i–v motions in Gm, but I don't hear G as tonic here). There's no chromaticism or fancy chord motion, it's just a minor dominant moving to the supertonic (ii) chord.

Comment: what do you mean by "the music being more centered in Gm or Dm"? are you talking about key change ?

Comment: @HyunYooPark Yes, I'm talking about a key change. I mean that it's unclear to me whether G is tonic there or if D is. If I had to guess, I would say D is tonic, and thus my reading would align with (2) above.

Comment: But what made you think the key has changed ? how could you define that ? I mean , from IVM7 V7 vi7 and all of sudden key change to dm ? doesn't it have to have more certain connection to make it happen ?

Comment: @HyunYooPark Only because I no longer hear C as tonic, although I do hear C as tonic in the FM7–G7–Am7 progression. Key changes can happen in all sorts of ways, but in short, if you feel like tonic is a different pitch than it was previously, then it's a key change.

Comment: @HyunYooPark But now, listening to the piece with better speakers, I hear that section in C (that is, neither Gm or Dm). I'll edit accordingly!

Comment: So if saying the [B] part is in C Maj key, how could you explain that chord progression ? Vm to ii ?

Comment: @HyunYooPark Yep! See my prior edit.

Comment: but how could I see this as a brief "i-v" if Gm i's actually v in this section ? and what do you mean by "it's just a minor dominant moving to the supertonic (ii) chord" ? didn''t you agree with me that the "v" is sub dominant "v" from Mixolydian scale ? then how could I see this as a dominant ? and also isn't ii also a sub dominant chord ?

Comment: Actually for me this song is in A minor! "VIb VIIb i" is all I see.

Comment: @HyunYooPark I'm saying that, if one hears Gm as a temporary tonic, then Gm temporarily becomes i, and therefore the Gm–Dm is i–v. As for "subdominant," are you using that term to mean "substitute dominant" or "the IV chord"?

Comment: @coconochao All you see, or hear? :-)

Comment: @Richard Ok I see..so is about my perspective I guess ?? and about the subdominant, I mean the IV and ii Chords function not the substitute dominant

Comment: @HyunYooPark In that case, I don't understand your question "and what do you mean by "it's just a minor dominant moving to the supertonic (ii) chord" ? didn''t you agree with me that the "v" is sub dominant "v" from Mixolydian scale ? then how could I see this as a dominant ?"

Comment: @Richard in my main text, I said I analyzed the v as a "Sub dominant" chord from mixolydian, and you said on your answer that my intuition about the Gm is absolutely correct. So that means you agreed with me that the v is functioning as a sub dominant. but on your answer at the last part your saying it's a  "minor dominant" moving in to the supertonic ii chord. so that confuses me

Answer (score 0):

everyone. I am from the country where Sakamoto was born. I suppose that Gm9->Dm9 should be interpreted as IIm->VIm in *F Major*, not in C Maj! Besides, Gm9->Bm7->E7 should be as IIm(in F Maj)->IIm(in A Minor)->V7(in A Minor) Hope this helps.